# How to add a file under `Pods` workspace when `pod install`?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Say `Podfile` is at `Project/Podfile`, the file I wanted to add is at `Project/1/2/3/README.md`

How to put that `README.md` after the `Podfile` (redline in the following pic) when run `pod install`

[image]